# Parsing a big textfile and saving information in a table

Tags: regex, vba, ms-access, text-parsing

I have a big text file (already 10Mb). something like this:

```
FESTWERT BMW_2
     LANGNAME "DFES / Gruppenstellvertreter für gemeinsame MIl Entprellung von DFC_DMTLmax"
   FUNKTION DFES 
     EINHEIT_W "-"
   WERT 253.25
END


KENNFELD CrCtl_StM.CrCtl_facPwrMaxaDem_MAP 6 6
   LANGNAME "GRA (Geschwindigkeits Regel Automat) - Zustandsautomat / leistungsabhängiger Faktor für max. Sollbeschleuniung"
   FUNKTION CrCtl_Gov 
   EINHEIT_X "km/h"
   EINHEIT_Y "kW"
   EINHEIT_W "-"
   ST/X   20.0000000000000000   50.0000000000000000   80.0000000000000000   120.0000000000000000   150.0000000000000000   200.0000000000000000   
   ST/Y   85.0000000000000000
   WERT   1.0000000000000000   1.0000000000000000   1.0000000000000000   0.7500000000000000   0.5468750000000000   0.2031250000000000   
   ST/Y   92.0000000000000000
   WERT   1.0000000000000000   1.0000000000000000   1.0000000000000000   0.7500000000000000   0.5468750000000000   0.2031250000000000   
   ST/Y   103.0000000000000000
   WERT   1.0000000000000000   1.0000000000000000   1.0000000000000000   0.7500000000000000   0.5468750000000000   0.2031250000000000   
   ST/Y   110.0000000000000000
   WERT   1.0000000000000000   1.0000000000000000   1.0000000000000000   0.7500000000000000   0.5468750000000000   0.2031250000000000   
   ST/Y   125.0000000000000000
   WERT   1.0000000000000000   1.0000000000000000   1.0000000000000000   0.7500000000000000   0.5468750000000000   0.2031250000000000   
   ST/Y   132.0000000000000000
   WERT   1.0000000000000000   1.0000000000000000   1.0000000000000000   0.7500000000000000   0.5468750000000000   0.2031250000000000   
END
```

I want to save these text structures in a table in access database:

[image]

I am using regular expression to read each line to make my desired structure and then save it in database ( I have many structure form in this text file)

I am using this code:

```
Option Compare Database

Sub ImportDcmlDaten(path As String, ID As Long)
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim ts As TextStream
Dim nameknl, nameknf, namefknl, namefwr, lien, DCMfilename As String
Dim testid As Integer

Dim regknf As New regexp
Dim regstx As New regexp
Dim regend As New regexp
Dim regxnum As New regexp
Dim regsty As New regexp
Dim regwert As New regexp
Dim regwertnum As New regexp
Dim regknl As New regexp
Dim regname As New regexp
Dim regfknl As New regexp
Dim regfstwrt As New regexp
Dim rega2l As New regexp
Dim regprodat As New regexp
Dim rega2lhex As New regexp

Dim regtxt As New regexp
Dim regwtxt As New regexp

Dim regeinheitx As New regexp
Dim regx As New regexp
Dim regeinheity As New regexp
Dim regeinheitwert As New regexp
Dim regfunktion As New regexp

   Dim swknnf, swknl, swfst As Boolean

Dim matchkennfeld, matchstx, matchend, matchxnum, matchynum, matchsty, matchwert, matchwertnum, matchkennlinie, matchname, matchfestkennlinie, matchprodat, matchfstwert, matcha2lhex, matchtxt As MatchCollection
Dim stxnums(0 To 1000) As String
Dim wertnums(0 To 1000) As String
Dim stynums(0 To 1000) As String
Dim X As Integer
Dim mycollection As New Collection

   Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qry As DAO.QueryDef

Set db = CurrentDb


DCMfilename = fso.GetFileName(path)
   Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(path, ForReading)

Set qry = db.QueryDefs("Test_qr_emptyDCM")
qry.Parameters("fzg_ID").Value = ID
Set rs = qry.OpenRecordset



'On Error GoTo Errhandler

regknf.Pattern = "KENNFELD\s+([\w|\s]*)"
regname.Pattern = "[\w|\s]*"
regknl.Pattern = "KENNLINIE\s+([\w|\s]*)"
regfstwrt.Pattern = "FESTWERT\s+([\w|\s]*)"
regfknl.Pattern = "FESTKENNLINIE\s+([\w|\s]*)"
regstx.Pattern = "(ST/X)\s*(-?[\d]*(\.)?[\d]*\s*)+"
regend.Pattern = "(END)"
regxnum.Pattern = "-?\d{1,}\.{0,1}\d{0,}"
regsty.Pattern = "(ST/Y)\s*(-?[\d]*(\.)?[\d]*\s*)+"
regwert.Pattern = "\bWERT\b\s*(-?[\d]*(\.)?[\d]*\s*)+"
regprodat.Pattern = "(Datensatz:|Projekt:)[\s\w*,*]*[\\\w]*"
rega2lhex.Pattern = "[\\][\w]*"
regxnum.Global = True
'regwertnum.Pattern = "-?\d{1,}\.{0,1}\d{0,}"
regwertnum.Global = True

regeinheitx.Pattern = "EINHEIT_X\s+[\""?\w\/\s\-\_]*"
regeinheity.Pattern = "EINHEIT_Y\s+[\""?\w\/\s\_\-]*"
regeinheitwert.Pattern = "EINHEIT_W\s+[\""?\w\/\s\-\_]*"
regfunktion.Pattern = "FUNKTION\s+[\""?\w\/\s\-\_]*"

regtxt.Pattern = "\bTEXT\b\s+[\""?\w\/\s\-\_]*"
regwtxt.Pattern = "\s+[\""?\w\/\s\-\_]*"
Do While Not ts.AtEndOfStream

line = ts.ReadLine



'specifying von KENNFELD Block
Set matchkennfeld = regknf.Execute(line)
Set matchend = regend.Execute(line)
Set matchstx = regstx.Execute(line)
Set matchsty = regsty.Execute(line)
Set matchwert = regwert.Execute(line)
Set matchkennlinie = regknl.Execute(line)
Set matchfestkennlinie = regfknl.Execute(line)
Set matchfstwert = regfstwrt.Execute(line)
Set matchprodat = regprodat.Execute(line)

Set matcheinheitx = regeinheitx.Execute(line)
Set matcheinheity = regeinheity.Execute(line)
Set matcheinheitwert = regeinheitwert.Execute(line)
Set matchfunktion = regfunktion.Execute(line)

Set matchtxt = regtxt.Execute(line)

If matchprodat.Count <> 0 Then
Set matcha2lhex = rega2lhex.Execute(matchprodat.Item(0))
 DCMfilename = DCMfilename + "<>" + Mid(matcha2lhex.Item(0), 2)
  If rs.Fields(0) = 0 Then
       MsgBox "Hier darf man nicht eine neue DCM einfügen"
       Exit Sub
  Else
       'MsgBox DCMfilename
       '
  End If
End If

If matchkennfeld.Count <> 0 Then
Set nameknf = regname.Execute(Mid(Trim(matchkennfeld.Item(0)), 9))
  swknnf = True
  X = 0
  W = 0
End If

If matcheinheitx.Count <> 0 And (swknnf = True Or swknl = True) Then
 Einheitx = Mid(Trim(matcheinheitx.Item(0)), 11)
End If

If matcheinheity.Count <> 0 And (swknnf = True) Then
 EinheitY = Mid(Trim(matcheinheity.Item(0)), 11)
End If

If matcheinheitwert.Count <> 0 And (swknnf = True Or swknl = True Or swfst = True) Then
 Einheitwert = Mid(Trim(matcheinheitwert.Item(0)), 11)
End If

If matchfunktion.Count <> 0 And (swknnf = True Or swknl = True Or swfst = True) Then
 Funktion = Mid(Trim(matchfunktion.Item(0)), 9)
End If

If matchfstwert.Count <> 0 Then
Set namefwr = regname.Execute(Mid(Trim(matchfstwert.Item(0)), 9))
swfst = True
End If

If matchkennlinie.Count <> 0 Then
  Set nameknl = regname.Execute(Mid(Trim(matchkennlinie.Item(0)), 10))
  swknl = True
End If

If matchfestkennlinie.Count <> 0 Then
  Set namefknl = regname.Execute(Mid(Trim(matchkennlinie.Item(0)), 14))
  swknl = True
End If

If matchend.Count <> 0 Then
 If swknnf = True Then
   'DoCmd.RunSQL ("INSERT INTO tb_DCM_Daten_info (EinheitX,EinheitY,Einheitwert,Name,Funktion,FzgID) VALUES('" & Trim(Einheitx) & "','" & Trim(EinheitY) & "','" & Trim(Einheitwert) & "','" & Trim(nameknf.Item(0)) & "','" & Trim(Funktion) & "','" & ID & "');")
   db.Execute ("INSERT INTO tb_DCM_Daten_info (EinheitX,EinheitY,Einheitwert,Name,Funktion,FzgID) VALUES('" & Trim(Einheitx) & "','" & Trim(EinheitY) & "','" & Trim(Einheitwert) & "','" & Trim(nameknf.Item(0)) & "','" & Trim(Funktion) & "','" & ID & "');")
 End If

 If swfst = True Then
   'DoCmd.RunSQL ("INSERT INTO tb_DCM_Daten_info (Einheitwert,Name,Funktion,FzgID) VALUES('" & Trim(Einheitwert) & "','" & Trim(namefwr.Item(0)) & "','" & Trim(Funktion) & "','" & ID & "');")
   db.Execute ("INSERT INTO tb_DCM_Daten_info (Einheitwert,Name,Funktion,FzgID) VALUES('" & Trim(Einheitwert) & "','" & Trim(namefwr.Item(0)) & "','" & Trim(Funktion) & "','" & ID & "');")
 End If


 If swknl = True Then
    For K = 0 To X - 1
     ' MsgBox nameknl.Item(0) + ":" + stxnums(K) + ":" + wertnums(K)
    ' DoCmd.RunSQL ("INSERT INTO tb_DCM_Daten (XValue,Wert,name,FzgID) VALUES ('" & stxnums(K) & "','" & wertnums(K) & "','" & Trim(nameknl.Item(0)) & "','" & ID & "');")
     db.Execute ("INSERT INTO tb_DCM_Daten (XValue,Wert,name,FzgID) VALUES ('" & stxnums(K) & "','" & wertnums(K) & "','" & Trim(nameknl.Item(0)) & "','" & ID & "');")
    Next K
    'DoCmd.RunSQL ("INSERT INTO tb_DCM_Daten_info (EinheitX,EinheitY,Einheitwert,Name,Funktion,FzgID) VALUES('" & Trim(Einheitx) & "','" & Trim(EinheitY) & "','" & Trim(Einheitwert) & "','" & Trim(nameknl.Item(0)) & "','" & Trim(Funktion) & "','" & ID & "');")
    db.Execute ("INSERT INTO tb_DCM_Daten_info (EinheitX,EinheitY,Einheitwert,Name,Funktion,FzgID) VALUES('" & Trim(Einheitx) & "','" & Trim(EinheitY) & "','" & Trim(Einheitwert) & "','" & Trim(nameknl.Item(0)) & "','" & Trim(Funktion) & "','" & ID & "');")
 End If
swknnf = False
swknl = False
swfst = False
X = 0
W = 0
Y = 0
Erase stxnums
Erase wertnums
Erase stynums
End If

If matchstx.Count <> 0 And (swknnf = True Or swknl = True) Then

 Set matchxnum = regxnum.Execute(Mid(Trim(matchstx.Item(0)), 5))
 For Each M In matchxnum
   stxnums(X) = M
   X = X + 1
 Next M
 ' Wir haben ein Array voll von STX Werte

End If

If matchsty.Count <> 0 And swknnf = True Then
  Set matchynum = regxnum.Execute(Mid(Trim(matchsty.Item(0)), 5))
End If

If (matchwert.Count <> 0 Or matchtxt.Count <> 0) And swfst = True Then

If matchwert.Count <> 0 Then
 Set matchwertnum = regxnum.Execute(Mid(Trim(matchwert.Item(0)), 5))
End If

If matchtxt.Count <> 0 Then
 Set matchwertnum = regwtxt.Execute(Mid(Trim(matchtxt.Item(0)), 5))
End If
 For Each M In matchwertnum
   'DoCmd.RunSQL ("INSERT INTO tb_DCM_Daten (Wert,name,FzgID) VALUES ('" & M & "','" & namefwr.Item(0) & "','" & ID & "');")
    db.Execute ("INSERT INTO tb_DCM_Daten (Wert,name,FzgID) VALUES ('" & M & "','" & namefwr.Item(0) & "','" & ID & "');")
 Next M
End If

If matchwert.Count <> 0 And swknnf = True Then
Set matchwertnum = regxnum.Execute(Mid(Trim(matchwert.Item(0)), 5))
For Each M In matchwertnum
  wertnums(W) = M
  W = W + 1
Next M
If W = X Then
For K = 0 To X - 1
 'MsgBox stxnums(K) + " " + matchynum(0) + " " + wertnums(K) + " " + nameknf.Item(0)
    'DoCmd.RunSQL ("INSERT INTO tb_DCM_Daten (XValue,YValue,Wert,name,FzgID) VALUES ('" & stxnums(K) & "','" & matchynum(0) & "','" & wertnums(K) & "','" & nameknf.Item(0) & "','" & ID & "');")
    db.Execute ("INSERT INTO tb_DCM_Daten (XValue,YValue,Wert,name,FzgID) VALUES ('" & stxnums(K) & "','" & matchynum(0) & "','" & wertnums(K) & "','" & nameknf.Item(0) & "','" & ID & "');")
 Next K
 W = 0
End If
End If

If matchwert.Count <> 0 And swknl = True Then
  Set matchwertnum = regxnum.Execute(Mid(Trim(matchwert.Item(0)), 5))
  For Each M In matchwertnum
     wertnums(W) = M
     W = W + 1
    Next M
End If
Loop
'DoCmd.RunSQL ("Update tb_KonzeptDaten  Set DCMFile=""" & DCMfilename & """ where (Konzept= " & ID & ")")
MsgBox "Die Daten sind Erfolgreich gespeichert"
Exit Sub

'Errhandler:
'MsgBox "An error has occurred. The macro will end."
 'hier musste ein Code sein, um die Vorherige Daten zu löschen
End Sub
```

but it takes a very long time to save this file into database (more than one hour) is there a better way to do this job? (only parsing the text file without saving in db takes 15 seconds)

Comment: Instead of adding the data one row at a time, perhaps you could have your current routine write the parsed data out to a CSV (comma-separated values) file and then use the VBA `DoCmd.TransferText` method to import the CSV file all at once?

Comment: You mean, that writing these info on a csv file takes less than time, as I write each row at a time?

Comment: The difference in performance would depend on a number of factors, but generally speaking a bulk import from a CSV file tends to be faster than individual INSERT statements. For example, say you're adding 100 rows to a table with 4 indexes on it: If you do that one row at a time then you update each of the 4 indexes 100 times. If you import all 100 rows at once then you'll probably just update each index once (to account for all 100 new rows).

Comment: Have you thought about creating a linked table against your parsed file (or even importing the CSV, as Gord has said), then maybe adapting your code to be a boolean function that takes all the parameters it needs, pulling a query with that function return value as a column and filtering for true, then doing a set-based insert to your production table?  In any case, if you can off-load the INSERTs to a set-based solution, I think you'd see a huge performance gain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comments to the question, I would recommend parsing the original text file and writing out a temporary CSV file like this:

```
94172,,,253.25,"BMW_2",230
94173,20.000000,85.000000,1.000000,"CrCtl_StM",230
94174,20.000000,85.000000,1.000000,"CrCtl_StM",230
```

... and then importing the CSV file using the VBA `DoCmd.TransferText` method.

Using a `Recordset` to perform the inserts (as suggested by the other answers) is certainly possible, but it can still be fairly slow unless you wrap the whole batch of insertions in a transaction, and doing that can lead to problems with "File sharing lock count exceeded" errors. There can also be other annoyances (like significant file bloat) when using that approach.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is most likely the large number of individual insert.

You could use a combination of `RecordSet` and transactions `BeginTrans` and `CommitTrans` as described in the answer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21992758/6206

Answer (score 0):

Remove your use of SQL insert commands and replace them with a reocrdset. Using a reocrdset that remains open (as opposed to many separate insert commands) is MANY times faster.